# formatting the x-axis label in plt.subplots

Tags: date, matplotlib, plot, subplot, dateformatter

problem:
how to make the date display in a beautiful form, in the format "month-year"?

my code:

```
decompose_data = seasonal_decompose(df_res_indx, model='additive')
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=4, sharex=True, figsize=(15, 8))

decompose_data.observed.plot(ax=axes[0], legend=False)
axes[0].set_ylabel('Observed', fontsize=12)

decompose_data.trend.plot(ax=axes[1], legend=False)
axes[1].set_ylabel('Trend', fontsize=12)

decompose_data.seasonal.plot(ax=axes[2], legend=False)
axes[2].set_ylabel('Seasonal', fontsize=12)

decompose_data.resid.plot(ax=axes[3], legend=False)
axes[3].set_ylabel('Residual', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

result:[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have some good examples in the [Date ticks labels doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html) of matplotlib.

The following `DateFormatter` should do the trick

```py
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# [...]

axes[3].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y'))
```